# NetBeans Build Error: Incorrect File Path in MakeFiles, Gets Overwritten During Compilation

Tags: c++, makefile, netbeans

I am trying to compile a project in NetBeans but I am getting a build error. One of the file paths in my MakeFiles is incorrect. My Build results:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'lib/lockdown/dist/Release//liblockdown.a', needed by 'dist/Release/GNU-Linux/RT_Camera_Capture'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/.netbeans/remote/192.168.2.77/frank-virtual-machine-Linux-x86_64/home/frank/NetBeansProjects/RT_SR_Cam_FINAL'
make[1]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk:66: .build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/.netbeans/remote/192.168.2.77/frank-virtual-machine-Linux-x86_64/home/frank/NetBeansProjects/RT_SR_Cam_FINAL'
make: *** [nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:40: .build-impl] Error 2
```

Obviously this file path is incorrect: 'lib/lockdown/dist/Release//liblockdown.a'

It should read as: 'lib/lockdown/dist/Release/GNU-Linux/liblockdown.a'

How do I fix it? I have tried editing the MakeFile directly but it gets overwritten when I compile. I imported this project from my other computer where it has no problem with compiling. The file path in the Makefile of the project on my original computer is correct.